# How to add column dynamically to Smart Forms table?

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

Is there a way that we can dynamically add column in the smartforms based on the record on the internal table?

Best Regards

Comment: I think no because we have to define the structure of smartforms beforehand.

Comment: Do you think there's a way the we can display records side by side in each template?

Comment: You can try another way: If you know exactly how many columns you need for each run, then create a proper template (with corresponding number of columns) for each case. Give your data 1 more column to identify which template will be used (of course, don't display it). That's all I can think of.

Comment: The column to be shown will be based on the saved record in the transparent table. anyways thank you for the response, best regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do it, but I can imagine a couple of workarounds you can try:

1. Put a condition in a table node column

[image]

This will hide the column if the record meets the condition, but leave there an empty space

2. Create two templates with different number of columns and show them using the alternative element.

This will make a clean solution when there will not be neither column nor empty space.